# Word Ladder runtime complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, code-complexity

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given a beginWord, say pig, and an endWord, say phi, and a list of words wordList, say [phg, phi]. We are allowed to change one character of beginword each time, and the transformed word needs to be in the wordList. I need an algorithm to find the minimal steps to achieve the transformation. In my example we can do pig -> phg -> phi. Also all the words involved are of the same length.

My solutions is to use BFS:

```
queue;
level = 0;
queue.add(beginWord);
while(queue is not empty){
    for(i looping from 0 to the size of the queue){
        curr = the first element in the queue;
        if curr is endWord, then returns level + 1;
        for(j starting from 0 to the length of curr){
            for(c starting from a to z){
                replaced = replace the jth character of curr with c;
                if we have never seen replaced before and it is contained in wordList, then add it to the queue.
            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

Now I am struggling to come up with the runtime complexity of this algorithm. Let us say that the length of the words is $M$, and the length of the wordList is `N`. My thinking is the following:

For each intermediate word, you have `26**M` choices and in the worst case one might need to visit all `N` words in the wordList, so in total one get `N * 26 ** M`. However, since we are requiring that all the transformations to be in the wordList, so actually, at each intermediate word, you have at most `N-1` choices. Thus, it seems to me that the runtime complexity should be `O(N(N  - 1))`.

Is that correct? I do not think so, because even though at each intermediate word, there is only `N-1` possible transformations, one do spend operations to check whether which `N-1` ones of them are valid by looping through the whole word and replaced each of its characters by `26` possibilities.

I know that the problem has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075364/time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-word-ladder). But no answer is accepted there and I do not agree with their analysis.

Comment: `26**M` represents every possible word with `M` letters. But you aren't searching every possible word. You're only changing one letter, so there are only `25 * M` possible next words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as far as the complexity of the algorithm is concerned:

```
queue;
level = 0;
queue.add(beginWord);
while(queue is not empty){
    for(i looping from 0 to the size of the queue){
        curr = the first element in the queue;
        if curr is endWord, then returns level + 1;
        for(j starting from 0 to the length of curr){
            for(c starting from a to z){
                replaced = replace the jth character of curr with c;
                if we have never seen replaced before and it is contained in wordList, then add it to the queue.
            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

Assuming the innermost loop uses a trie or hashtable for lookups (won't get more efficient than that), the inner condition takes `O(n)`:

```
while(queue is not empty){
    for(i looping from 0 to the size of the queue){
        curr = the first element in the queue;
        if curr is endWord, then returns level + 1;
        for(j starting from 0 to the length of curr){
            for(c starting from a to z){
                O(n)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The next inner most loop iterates 26 times, so still `O(n)`:

```
while(queue is not empty){
    for(i looping from 0 to the size of the queue){
        curr = the first element in the queue;
        if curr is endWord, then returns level + 1;
        for(j starting from 0 to the length of curr){
            O(n)
        }
    }
}
```

The next loop iterates over the length of the string, so again `n` steps. The additional steps are either constant-time or linear (`O(n)`), so we can just ignore them:

```
while(queue is not empty){
    for(i looping from 0 to the size of the queue){
        O(n ^ 2)
    }
}
```

This for-loop is now fairly useless. We can simply remove it at instead poll the queue directly in the `while`-loop. The `while`-loop takes `O(m)` steps where `m` is the number of words in the word-list. So in total the time-complexity is `O(n^2 * m)`.